# Why is VSCode killing my language server when I open the source control tab?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, language-server-protocol

I'm working on a language server extension right now and keep getting annoyed because after opening the source control tab once in a session, VSC sends a shutdown request to my language server. It never restarts it so I just have to restart VSC instead.

[image]

Anyone know if there's some configuration I'm missing or way to disable this behavior? It's quite inconvenient...

Comment: I don't see the reason the vscode-extensions tag wouldn't apply here. The extension is literally what provides the language server with configuration - there's every possibility that it's what I have to change to fix this behavior. Especially because VSC does not even wait for the language server's response before sending a shutdown request.

Comment: [https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/35196](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/35196) I think you can get any hint by read from this article

Comment: @KaumadieKariyawasam Thanks for your comment. I found that issue previously, but it has nothing to do with my situation.